# By prolonging its sides, one can partition an arbitrary polygon into convex polygons

Tags: euclidean-geometry, plane-geometry, convex-geometry

It is straightforward to prove by induction on the number of sides that a convex n-sided polygon can be partitioned into n-2 triangles. My question here is whether there is an analogous proof that an arbitrary polygon can be partitioned into convex polygons by prolonging its sides (and if so, whether there is a known function of n that determines the number of convex polygons in the partition). Intuitively, this seems correct, and the result is immediate for n=3, but I am having some difficulty extending the argument to the case n>3. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Try to partition a pentagon into quadrilaterals.

Comment: @DS Thank you for your reply. I'm not sure I understand your hint. A (regular) pentagon is convex and hence the partitioning into convex polygons is trivial.

Comment: I think I don't understand your question. It is known that we can partition **any** polygon into triangles, so I think you're asking for partitioning into polygons with more than three sides

Comment: @DS To prove that one can partition any polygon into triangles, one can first prove that any polygon can be partitioned into convex polygons, which can in turn be partitioned into triangles. As I mentioned in my original question, the latter result can be established by means of a straightforward induction argument on the number of sides; what I am curious about though is how to demonstrate that prolonging/extending the edges of an arbitrary polygon yields a partition into convex polygons.

Comment: Can you give an example, maybe a diagram?